# How to find the CSS to change

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a newbie so forgive me stupid questions ˆˆ

I am creating a website with bootstrap. It all works fine, yet I want to overwrite some CSS. In the attached picture you see how I used the developer tool to inspect my site. Now I see a lot of CSS but I find it hard to know how to write it in my own CSS styles document.

When you look at the menu item you see "Food" which is within  and the `li` class is `.active`
Above that there is `nav navbar-nav` and above that is `navbar-collapse collapse`...

Now I want to change the font color of Food and of the other buttons and I want to change the background color of only the buttons.

When I write:

`.active {color: red;}`

Nothing changes... so do I have to add all the classes before and if so when to use a point and not...

`.navbar-collapse collapse .nav navbar-nav .active`

But this somehow does not overrule the bootstrap.min...

Help is appreciated
Thank you in advance!
And be safe people, we are in this together

[my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SdfB.jpg)

Comment: Hey Hisham, thanks, I used the select and was able to copy the original css that is used by the element and change it as I want! I found that in the developer tool I can simply copy the css, paste it in my own css styles and change it ... learning !! thanks

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: You should use a more specific selector or use the same selector but make sure it is set later in the flow with the same selector. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Though you most certainly can override all of the css with various methods such as using `!important;` (not recommended as it is considered bad practice to do so), since you are using bootstrap there is a much easier way for you to achieve what you want.

The classes `text-danger` for the font color, and `bg-white` for the background should give you what you seek, however i recommend you check out Bootstrap's documentation for the various other kinds of classes you can use to modify your font or background.

Answer (score 0):

It worked using the Chrome developer tool, inspect the element, copy the css from the developer tool and paste it in my own css

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the bootstrap style

1. inspect the element(Ctrl+ Shift+I)
2. in you can see style and url of style , you can edit style, then click url of style  then Ctrl+A then Ctrl+C then you go to bootstrap css and delete all then paste you style
   that you edited